# "allowClearUserData" = "false" in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: java, android, manifest

What is the allowClearUserData attribute do in the android manifest file?

Comment: If any answer solved the question, please accept it for future reference.

Comment: Thanks! However to accept any answer please click on the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: Done it is ticked. Please continue helping me in future questions

Comment: Sure! Glad to help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The allowClearUserData is an option that let's the application  specify if the user's data can/cannot be deleted. By default, this flag is set to true. However it can be changed to false. The attribute can be set for your app. However any other app cannot use this attribute to clear your app's user data.he attribute allows boolean value, that is either "true" or "false". 
If set to true, the application manager has the right to clear the data.

Example:

```
<application>
<application android:allowClearUserData=["true" | "false"] 
</application>
```

This must be placed within the android manifest file.

Comment: I have edited the answer. The user data refers to settings, data and information of an user saved in the app.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by your question regards internal storage?

Answer (score 6):

Per the [source code](http://android.macpod.net/xref/android-7.1.1_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/attrs_manifest.xml) for that field:

> Option to let applications specify that user data can/cannot be
> cleared. This flag is turned on by default. *This attribute is
> usable only by applications included in the system image. Third-party
> apps cannot use it.*
>
> `<attr name="allowClearUserData" format="boolean" />`